# Sur l'inexistence d'un adverbe distributif pour le locatif

Tags: vocabulaire, pronoms, adverbes

En lisant la page Wiki sur les pronoms en français, j'ai remarqué un vide dans l'un des tableaux :

- déterminant : tout, chaque
- pronom humain : tout le monde, chacun
- pronom non humain : tout, chaque
- pronom sélectif : tous, chacun
- adverbe locatif : partout, **????**
- adverbe temporel : toujours, chaque fois

Effectivement, je n'ai connaissance d'aucun mot ou locution calquée sur chaqu- qui acte au locatif. "Chaque endroit/lieu" est grammaticalement correct mais compte tenu de l'habituelle (et souvent redondante) richesse lexicale du français, je trouve bizarre qu'il n'y ait pas de mot pour ça.

Il en va de même pour le temporel qui ne possède pas de mot calqué sur autr- (autre, autrui, autre chose, autre, ailleurs, **???**). Quid de ces absences ?

Comment: Ce serait en fait « en chaque lieu » qu'il faudrait utiliser pour combler le vide.

Comment: Pour ce qui est du temporel composé avec autre... SISISI... on en avait un. Bien! Tout propre! Tout comme il faut... en... moyen français : ***autrefois***. Je ne sais dire pourquoi mais, vers 1200 et des, il se spécialise pour ne plus concerner **que** le passé. C'est bien dommage puisque, pour cela on a déjà antan, jadis...

Comment: ici?...........

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez "en tous lieux" fonctionnerait aussi.

Comment: @aCOSwt D’**autrefois** passé à un usage spécialisé, il nous restera toujours les morceaux brisés du puzzle, que l’on peut encore à ce jour assembler en **une autre fois**, qui se tourne indifféremment vers le passé ou l'avenir, et peut même à l'occasion se teindre d’une nuance de **jamais** (davantage de détails sur ce dernier usage une autre fois).

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait ajouter 'a chaque endroit' ou 'dans chaque lieu'.  Mais c'est vraiment absurde de forcer une symmetrie dans le language qui n'existe pas.  Depuis quand on est oblige de remplir toutes les cases, et de la meme maniere en plus?